# Showing attributes of another model in CGridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii

In Yii I am doing multimodel.My database is something like this

```
 +++++ Group ++++++
 id
 name

 +++++ Member ++++++
 id
 group_id
 firstname
 lastname
 membersince
```

In Group controller I want to show Member's attributes.Everything is working fine but when I am using manage option from the menu it is showing the attributes for both models but in two different grid-view.I want to show both models attributes in a single grid-view.
 The code for Member controller is like this

```
  public function actionAdmin()
  {
    $model=new Group('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Group']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_GET['Group'];
    }
    $member=new Member('search');
    $member->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Member']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_GET['Member'];
    }
    $this->render('admin',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'member'=>$member,
    ));
  }
```

for View in Group admin code is like this

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'member-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
  'filter'=>$model,
  'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
      'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
  ),
));
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                  'id'=>'member-grid',
                  'dataProvider'=>$member->search(),
                  'filter'=>$member,
                  'columns'=>array(
                    'firstname',
                    'lastname',
                    array(
                      'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    ),                    
                            ),
                 ));
```

Here I have used CGridView for two times to show models for both attributes. So can someone tell me how to show models in a single 
CGridView.Any help and suggestions will be highly appriciable.
**[Updated]**
Relations in Models:
Group Model

```
public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'member' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Member', 'group_id'),
    );
  }
```

Member Model:

```
 public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Group', 'group_id'),
    );
  }
```

Comment: if you show your relations between the tables it'll be easy, please show the code for `public function relations(){...}` function in your models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way to access related model fields in yii is to use something like this
`$model->relatedModel->field` -- this can be used if there is a **has_one**, or **belongs_to** relation between the models.
So in your case, you can access the *group name of a member* using the code
`$memberModel->group->name`

But when you need to access related model fields for **has_many**, or **many_many** relation types, you will need to do something like
`$model->relatedModel[arrayIndex]->field`
This is because there are many related models in this case, and yii automatically gives you the related model in an array.
In your case a *group has many members* and to access a particular member(say the first member, i.e *arrayIndex = 0*) of a group you can use `$groupModel->members[0]->firstname`
Now to coming to your exact question, first of all, you do not need to declare or initialize or pass the $member model. So your controller action can be

```
public function actionAdmin(){
  $model=new Group('search');
  $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
  if(isset($_GET['Group'])){
     $model->attributes=$_GET['Group'];
  }
  $this->render('admin',array(
     'model'=>$model
     )
  );
}
```

Then obviously in your view you don't need the two grid-views

```
<?php 
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
     'id'=>'member-grid',
     'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
     'filter'=>$model,
     'columns'=>array(
         'id',
         'name',
         array( // this is for your related group members of the current group
            'name'=>'members.firstname', // this will access the attributeLabel from the member model class, and assign it to your column header
            'value'=>'$data->members[0]->firstname', // this will access the current group's 1st member and give out the firstname of that member
            'type'=>'raw' // this tells that the value type is raw and no formatting is to be applied to it
         ),
         array(
           'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
         ),
      ),
   ));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @bool.dev for your help but here I am getting error as Property "Group.members" is not defined. I think I am getting this error as in Group table there is no any attribute like firstname.Firstname attribute is present in Member table. So how to pass the firstname attribute of Member into Group view.

Comment: ok, change that to member, as in member.firstname in the view, instead of members.firstname, also then your value will be changed to $data->member[0]->firstname

Comment: Thanks @bool.dev for your reply.But it is showing the error.Now t is showing error like Trying to get property of non-object .

Comment: It is showing error in view file of Group. In this line 'value'=>$data->member->name,

Comment: well it should be $data->member[0]->firstname

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7330/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-newuser)